# Racket Regex / String Replace

Tags: racket

is there a built-in function in drracket which allows me to check if a specific data is included in a string?

For example I want to get back a result "true" for any string with the letter "a" in them.

"fate" -> true
"fote" -> false

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Racket includes a regular expressions package.  You could use

```
(regexp-match <pattern> <input>)
```

There are probably implementations of `substring?` available, like in SRFI-13.